# Django cookiecutter docker build failing: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I've been using the cookiecutter docker setup for local development which has been working wonderfully. I'm now ready to build and deploy a production version of my application.

I've followed the instructions [here](http://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html) and [here](http://adamantine.me/2017/10/19/deploying-cookiecutter-django-with-docker-compose/).

It all seems pretty straight-forward, however when I run the build command:

```
$ docker-compose -f production.yml build
```

I get a RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 121, in perform_command
File "compose/cli/command.py", line 40, in project_from_options
File "compose/cli/command.py", line 110, in get_project
File "compose/config/config.py", line 377, in load
File "compose/config/config.py", line 508, in process_config_file
File "compose/config/config.py", line 499, in 
interpolate_config_section
File "compose/config/interpolation.py", line 44, in 
interpolate_environment_variables
File "compose/config/interpolation.py", line 44, in <genexpr>
File "compose/config/interpolation.py", line 39, in process_item
File "compose/config/interpolation.py", line 39, in <genexpr>
File "compose/config/interpolation.py", line 54, in interpolate_value
...
...
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I'm at a loss of what might be causing this. The main difference between my local and production setup are the production.yml and .django env settings. See below. Ideas? Thanks!

**production.yml**

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
  postgres_backup: {}
  caddy: {}

services: &django
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
      - ./.envs/.production/.celery
    command: /gunicorn.sh

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres

  caddy:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/caddy/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - caddy:/root/.caddy
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.caddy
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:443"

  redis:
    image: redis:3.0

    celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres

    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
      - ./.envs/.production/.celery
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker.sh

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres

    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
      - ./.envs/.production/.celery
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat.sh
```

**.django**

```
# General
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=True
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=auto generated long key
DJANGO_ADMIN_URL=auto generated admin url
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=my deploy ip

# Security
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TIP: better off using DNS, however, redirect is OK too
DJANGO_SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=False

# Email
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MAILGUN_API_KEY=
DJANGO_SERVER_EMAIL=
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=

# AWS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=

# django-allauth
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION=True

# Gunicorn
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEB_CONCURRENCY=4

# Sentry
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DJANGO_SENTRY_DSN=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you ran into [an old bug](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/454).

Does any of your auto-generated long string start with `$`? If that's the case, it's causing django-environ to try to interpolate the value and crashing. Try re-generating these, and it should fix it.

Comment: @phil-butcher did my answer solved your problem? Would you mind accepting it if that is the case? Thanks